# Getting image size programmatically

Tags: android, image, picasso

Is there any way to find the size of an image which is set to an image view
?

Answer (score 1):

There is a **resize** method in Picasso which takes in height and width as a parameter.

So you can use something like this-

```
Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.image)
    .resize(600, 200) // resizes the image to these dimensions
    .into(imageViewResize);
```

**But** if you want the dimensions after the image has been set into the **ImageView**, you should be using getHeight and getWidth methods but make sure the ImageView has **wrap_content** as **layout_height and layout_width**.

```
     int width = imageViewResize.getWidth();
     int height = imageViewResize.getHeight();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of loading image into an `ImageView`, load it into a `com.squareup.picasso.Target` like below.

```
Picasso.with(this)
    .load(url)
    .into(new Target() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable d) {}

        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap b, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
            int bitmapWidth = b.getWidth();             
            mImageView.setImageBitmap(b);
        }
        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable d) {
            // TODO: Implement this method
        }
    });
```

Comment: It's not working fine.where I need to give the image view id.How can I save the image into local memory after re sizing in Picasso?